# Where can I see my USCIS Online Account Number?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

On my N-400 Application for Naturalization form online, I am asked to indicate whether I have a USCIS Online Account Number, and if so, to
provide it. Where can I see my USCIS Online Account Number?

The form says:

> What is your USCIS Online Account Number?
> You can find your USCIS Online Account Number by signing in to your account and going to your profile page.
>
> If you previously filed an application, petition, or request using the USCIS online filing system, provide the USCIS Online Account Number you were issued.
>
> If you previously filed certain applications, petitions, or requests on a paper form via a USCIS Lockbox facility, you may have received a USCIS Online Account Access Notice issuing you a USCIS Online Account Number. You can find this number at the top of the notice. The USCIS Online Account Number is not the same as an A-Number. The USCIS Online Account Number was previously called the USCIS Electronic Immigration System (USCIS ELIS) Number.

But I can't see any USCIS Online Account Number by signing in to my account and going to my profile page. I tried going to:

- https://my.uscis.gov/account/applicant
- https://my.uscis.gov/account/applicant/settings
- https://myaccount.uscis.gov/users/edit

I also don't see any USCIS Online Account Number on the Forms I-797C (Notice of Action) that I received when applying for US lawful permanent residency a few years ago (I-140 Immigrant Petition for Alien Worker then I-485 Application to Register Permanent Residence or Adjust Status) via a US attorney.

---

Screenshot from [https://my.uscis.gov/apply/v2/naturalization/[ID]/additional-information](https://my.uscis.gov/apply/v2/naturalization/%5BID%5D/additional-information):

[image]

Comment: Have you ever filed anything online?

Comment: @littleadv only AR-11s.

Comment: So no applications, petitions or requests? Have you read the text on the screenshot?

Comment: @littleadv yes it says "You can find your USCIS Online Account Number by signing in to your account and going to your profile page."

Comment: "If you previously filed...."

Comment: @littleadv doesn't exclude the possiblity of the number being only on the website.

Comment: I'm trying to explain to you that the message tells you in what case you'd have that number, and its not your case.

Comment: @littleadv thanks, I don't find the message clear so I wanted to confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may not have USCIS Online Account Number, even if one has an USCIS Online Account and even if one has previously filed paper application/petitions/requests/.

Reddit user [adapt2](https://www.reddit.com/user/adapt2) [mentioned](https://redd.it/ty5ref):

> The USCIS OAC is issued to those who have at any point filed an online petition/application. I-485 form is not online yet, so you never receive OAC when you file that form. If you never filed an online petition, you do not have an OAC.

And Reddit user [DoesntCheckOutUname](https://www.reddit.com/user/DoesntCheckOutUname) [mentioned](https://redd.it/ty5ref):

> When I firstly filed my N-400, I didn't put any USCIS Online Account Number in the form. But when they sent the receipt, there was a USCIS Online Account Number on the Notice.